# Interpreting a "sunrise function": $t=-1.4\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{365} (d-75)\right) + 7$

Tags: trigonometry

> In Africa, the time for sunrise any day during the year can be shown as the formula:
>   $$t=-1.4\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{365} (d-75)\right) + 7$$ 
>   where $t$ is the time in hours after midnight
>   and $d$ is the number of the day in the year (forget leap year)
>   $d=1$ is Jan. 1st
>
> a) What are the earliest and latest sunrise times (in Hr:Min format) during $1$ year?
>
> b) The servant's birthday is on March 15th. Determine the time (in Hr:min format) the sun rose on the day of the servant's birthday.
>
> c) Determine on which days (month/day) of the year the sun rose at $7$:$30$am?

My work:

a) I add $-1.4 + 7$ to get min, and I add $1.4+7$ to get max time

b) I get $7$:$01$ am in the morning: I set march 15th as the 74th day, and plug it into the original equation to get the time in hours, and then I convert $7.02$ into hr:min format to get the 7:01am.

c) This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Hey, I've tried attempting this question

Comment: for a) I add -1.4 + 7 to get min and I add 1.4+7 to get max time

Comment: for b) I get 7:01 am in the morning - i set march 15th as the 74th day and plug it into the original equation to get the time in hours and then i convert 7.02  into hr:min format to get the 7:01am.

Comment: for c) i'm not exactly sure what to do i'm stuck can someone help and check to see if my answers are right

Comment: can someone help me out?

Comment: Just edit your attempts into the question instead of writing comments.

Comment: Ok will do that for next time, can you assist me with C) of this question?

Comment: @user222031 do you know how to tackle it

Comment: Can someone help me out on this one

Comment: You asked this question [previously](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744166/trig-application-question), then deleted it. Delete-and-repost is not the appropriate way to attract answers (or handle downvotes); rather, you should simply edit your initial questions with more information, etc, to improve its quality. Keep this in mind for the future. (FYI: Periodically commenting "can someone help me" won't grab anyone's attention.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have solved a and b, let's see c:
$$
t=-1.4\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{365} (d-75)\right) + 7 \rightarrow d= 75+\frac{365}{2\pi}\arcsin\left(\frac{7-t}{1.4}\right)
$$

Comment: arcsin means the inverse of sin right? sin^-1?

Comment: would you leave the answer at this or go further?

Comment: yes, it is. you now need to substitute with $t=7.5$ to get $d$.

Comment: okay one sec let me try it and let you know what i get

Comment: i get 55 days as the answer

Comment: I have got $53.78$, so you could say $54$.

Comment: Okay thank you and how about the second date? it asks for more than one date right?

Comment: Yes, there is another one at $279$

Comment: how is that found? see this is what i am not getting - how do we find the second xvalue?

Comment: We know that $\sin(\pi-x) = \sin(x)$, hence, the second value can be obtained from $75+\frac{365}{2\pi}\left(\pi-\arcsin\left(\frac{7-t}{1.4}\right)\right)$